# Git - Can I pull commits to a remote branch from an updated other branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

In this scenario I have 3 branches:

- master
- dev1
- dev2

I created dev1 and dev2 from master at commit "a". I merge dev1 into master with commits "b", "c" and "d". master now has commits a>b>c>d

At the same time I work on dev2 and do commits "e", "f" and "g". If I now do the command (on dev2 branch)

```
git pull origin master
```

My dev2 branch will contain all changes (if no conflicts) from commits a, b c d, e f g.

Or will it just pull down the changes locally to be committed again?

In this scenario I was to carry on developing on dev2, but without the headache of worrying about dev1 again. I.e I want to delete dev1 and incorporate all changes onto dev2 to carry on developing on dev2 branch... is the pull the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Stay on `dev2`. Say `git fetch` to make sure everything is up to date. Now say `git rebase master`. You have now caused `e` (and what follows) to chain on to the end of `d`, giving you this:

```
a - b - c - d (master) 
                  \ 
                   e - f - g (dev2)
```

...which sounds like what you want. As for `dev1`, if you don't need it for anything, just delete it; it became more or less pointless after you merged it to `master`.

(It isn't quite clear from your description what, if anything, you want to do about `master`, so in my instructions I have left it where it is.)